# TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined after page re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass a props to another component, and it won't read it for some reason.

Here's the parent code that I'm using to call my modal component

```
<OrderActionModal
        show={modalShow}
        onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
        orders={props.orders}
      />
```

(props.orders is from another parent code)

Here's the child code from the modal component

```
{props.orders[0].status === "open" && (
              <Button
                variant="dark"
                style={{
                  fontSize: "13px",
                  marginRight: 10,
                  marginBottom: 15,
                }}
                onClick={(e) => updateStatusHandler(e, "paid")}
              >
                <motion.div
                  whileHover={{ scale: 1.06 }}
                  whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
                >
                  &nbsp;Konfirmasi Pembayaran
                </motion.div>
              </Button>
            )}
```

Here's the result

[image: result]

I tried just using props.orders.status but there's no result. By adding the '[0]', I got the result that I wanted, however every time the page re-renders, I get that error again.

Comment: You need to map through the orders. `props.orders && props.orders.map(order => { code here })`

Comment: Are you sure that your prop.orders is an array and not an object?

Comment: When the error occurs, what is the value of `props.orders`?  Does the array *have* an element in it?  Immediately before you try to reference `props.orders[0]`, put a `console.log(props.orders)`.  What is logged to the console just before the error?

Comment: @JoelHager I tried that and it didn't work

Comment: @ManojSethi it is an object, I don't exactly know why I put the '[0]', but it works, but only if I never re-render the page

Comment: @David when I do the `console.log(props.orders[0].status)` it has the status value "open" that I was looking for, but when I do `console.log(props.orders.status)`, it shows undefined

Comment: @WilliamMandang: If `console.log(props.orders[0].status)` prints `"open"` then `props.orders[0]` is definitely *not* `undefined` as described in the question.  You may need to provide a [mcve] to demonstrate the problem, since the debugging information you're providing isn't consistent.

Comment: @David that's what I'm trying to figure out. When I `console.log(props.orders[0].status)` in the parent component, it prints the status value that I wanted. But when I pass it to the child component, it works at first, but after I refresh the page it gives me the undefined error.

Comment: @WilliamMandang: (1) Don't log it in the parent component, log it *immediately before* the line which causes the error.  (2) Don't log `props.orders[0].status` if *that's what causes the error*, log `props.orders` and see what it actually contains.  (3) Are you fully reloading the page, or just re-rendering the component?  The description isn't clear on that.  In any event, if `props.orders[0]` is `undefined` then it's undefined.  Where is that data coming from?  What sets that value?  You may need to trace that back even further in your debugging, currently it's not in the sample shown.

Answer (score 0):

`{props.orders[0].status === "open" && (`

That's the code that fails. When the page re-renders, `orders[0]` is undefined and then *in a nutshell*, you're trying to read `undefined.status`

One lovely solution is to add `?` as a null-check (I think it's only available from ES2017)

For example,

```js
{props.orders?.[0]?.status === "open" && (
              <Button
                variant="dark"
                style={{
                  fontSize: "13px",
                  marginRight: 10,
                  marginBottom: 15,
                }}
                onClick={(e) => updateStatusHandler(e, "paid")}
              >
                <motion.div
                  whileHover={{ scale: 1.06 }}
                  whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
                >
                  &nbsp;Konfirmasi Pembayaran
                </motion.div>
              </Button>
            )}
```

Or you could go old-school and do an inline null-check

```js
{props.orders && props.orders[0] && props.orders[0].status === "open" && (
              <Button
                variant="dark"
                style={{
                  fontSize: "13px",
                  marginRight: 10,
                  marginBottom: 15,
                }}
                onClick={(e) => updateStatusHandler(e, "paid")}
              >
                <motion.div
                  whileHover={{ scale: 1.06 }}
                  whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
                >
                  &nbsp;Konfirmasi Pembayaran
                </motion.div>
              </Button>
            )}
```

The solution will result in `undefined` because when the above statement will be executed, it will look something like this ->

`{[] && undefined && ( <Button ... )}`
which will result in the condition showing you `undefined`

If you want to display nothing, you should use a ternary operator. For example:

```js
{props.orders && props.orders[0] && props.orders[0].status === "open" ? (
              <Button
                variant="dark"
                style={{
                  fontSize: "13px",
                  marginRight: 10,
                  marginBottom: 15,
                }}
                onClick={(e) => updateStatusHandler(e, "paid")}
              >
                <motion.div
                  whileHover={{ scale: 1.06 }}
                  whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
                >
                  &nbsp;Konfirmasi Pembayaran
                </motion.div>
              </Button>
            )
: null
}
```

Comment: I didn't get an error but it gives me undefined instead